# NextGen plugin and SQL syntax error

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, syntax, nextgen-gallery

I am trying to get the NextGen gallery Id dynamically and getting SQL syntax error

> `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax`

Have a look on below code where I am making mistake

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
global $post;
$galleryid = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_gallery', true ); 
$pictures=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_ngg_pictures WHERE galleryid='$galleryid'");
?>
```

Or may be I am doing it wrong way?

Comment: Is that the full error message you're getting?

Comment: The database is handling WP so yeah I think that is the genuine error message :)

Comment: @PeeHaa - I thought it normally included the part of the SQL statement that caused the actual error.

Comment: I am entering my sql manually in my phpmyadmin db. The complete error message is as below
-----------------------------------------------------
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT * FROM wp_ngg_pictures WHERE galleryid='$galleryid'"' at line 1
--------------------------------------------

Comment: @WebWebby - Of course you get that error in phpmyadmin, that's because `$galleryid` isn't defined there.

Comment: Btw. This is a good example of how not to do it ! You open doors for sql-injection use prepared statements or at least an mysql escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite likely that `$galleryid` has an unexpected value, but nevertheless you should use the `prepare()` method that Wordpress provides for your queries:

```
$pictures = $wpdb->get_results( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "SELECT * FROM wp_ngg_pictures WHERE galleryid = %d",
        $galleryid
    )
);
```

If you want to test the query, you can take the output of `prepare()` and run that in phpMyAdmin.